# Touchpad not working ( Satellite P850-337 ) - 14.10

Tags: 14.10, touchpad

Touchpad is not working since 14.04, and I have upgraded to 14.10 just in order to make it work, but I just discovered it didn`t work.

I have tried to blacklist and unblacklist i2c_i801 and i2c_hid, didn`t work. Please note that it works just fine on Windows 8.

Here is my `xinput --list` output.

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]  
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎜   ↳ HID 0b38:0010                             id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎜   ↳ USB Mouse                                 id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎜   ↳ USB Mouse                                 id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎜   ↳ MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (ene_ir)            id=18   [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]  
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ HID 0b38:0010                             id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD                   id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Toshiba input device                      id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ ENE eHome Infrared Remote Receiver        id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I also tried (without success):

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse  
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

Some more details:

```
$ synclient -l

Parameter settings:
    LeftEdge                = 1766
    RightEdge               = 5384
    TopEdge                 = 1640
    BottomEdge              = 4500
    FingerLow               = 5
    FingerHigh              = 5
    MaxTapTime              = 180
    MaxTapMove              = 235
    MaxDoubleTapTime        = 180
    SingleTapTimeout        = 180
    ClickTime               = 100
    EmulateMidButtonTime    = 0
    EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 282
    EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 7
    VertScrollDelta         = 1
    HorizScrollDelta        = 1
    VertEdgeScroll          = 0
    HorizEdgeScroll         = 0
    CornerCoasting          = 0
    VertTwoFingerScroll     = 1
    HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 1
    MinSpeed                = 1
    MaxSpeed                = 1.75
    AccelFactor             = 0.0373
    TouchpadOff             = 0
    LockedDrags             = 1
    LockedDragTimeout       = 5000
    RTCornerButton          = 2
    RBCornerButton          = 3
    LTCornerButton          = 0
    LBCornerButton          = 0
    TapButton1              = 1
    TapButton2              = 3
    TapButton3              = 0
    ClickFinger1            = 1
    ClickFinger2            = 3
    ClickFinger3            = 0
    CircularScrolling       = 0
    CircScrollDelta         = 0.100007
    CircScrollTrigger       = 0
    CircularPad             = 0
    PalmDetect              = 0
    PalmMinWidth            = 10
    PalmMinZ                = 200
    CoastingSpeed           = 20
    CoastingFriction        = 50
    PressureMotionMinZ      = 30
    PressureMotionMaxZ      = 160
    PressureMotionMinFactor = 1
    PressureMotionMaxFactor = 1
    ResolutionDetect        = 1
    GrabEventDevice         = 0
    TapAndDragGesture       = 1
    AreaLeftEdge            = 0
    AreaRightEdge           = 0
    AreaTopEdge             = 0
    AreaBottomEdge          = 0
    HorizHysteresis         = 8
    VertHysteresis          = 8
    ClickPad                = 1
    RightButtonAreaLeft     = 3575
    RightButtonAreaRight    = 0
    RightButtonAreaTop      = 4133
    RightButtonAreaBottom   = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaLeft    = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaRight   = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaTop     = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaBottom  = 0
```

And

```
$ cat /proc/bus/input/devices

I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=0007 Version=01b1
N: Name="SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse1 event6 
B: PROP=5
B: EV=b
B: KEY=e520 10000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=660800011000003
```

Found a workaround: Restart the laptop, boot on Windows, press fn+f5, restart the computer, boot on ubuntu.

The touchpad will work but only until you shutdown the computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I solved the problem by pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> during grub boot screen. I have also added to `~/.bashrc`

```
synclient FingerLow=38 && synclient FingerHigh=43 && 
synclient VertScrollDelta=-111 && synclient HorizScrollDelta=-111 &&
synclient PalmDetect=1 && synclient CoastingSpeed=0 && 
synclient LockedDrags=0
```